# Unions and Intersections of Sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set of sequences $\omega$ that are sequences of $0$ and $1$ and I want to express the set $L := \{\omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n}(\omega) = \infty\}$

as unions or intersections of $C_{n}$, where $C_{n}:=\{\omega: \omega_{n}=1\}$, and $S_{n}$ is $n$th partial sum of the sequence.

Does it make sense to describe $L$ as $\bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{n \geq N} C_{n}$, for some $N \in \mathcal{N}$? I think this checks out but am not sure of my intuition.

Comment: Does $S_n$ denote the $n$th partial sum of the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

This set almost has the correct form. It should be $A=\cap_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\cup_{n\geq N}C_n$.

To see this, let $\omega\in A$ and note that for every $N\in \mathbb{N},$ there exists some $n\geq N$ such that $\omega(n)=1$. Thus, define $n_1=1$ and, inductively, $n_k\geq n_{k-1}+1$ such that $\omega(n_k)=1$. Thus, $\limsup_{N\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\omega(j)\geq \limsup_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N}\omega(n_k)=\infty$. Hence, $A\subseteq L$.

On the other hand, if $\omega\in A^c,$ we see that there exists some $N_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\omega(n)=0$ for all $n\geq N_0$. Thus, $\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^N \omega(j)=\sum_{j=1}^{N_0-1} \omega(j)<\infty$. Hence, $A^c\subseteq L^c,$ and thus, $A=L$.

In probability, the set $A$ is known as $(C_n\textrm{ infinitely often}),$ which should give some intuition as to why this is the set you want.

Comment: As a note, the set you wrote is $(C_n\textrm{ eventually}),$ and this is stronger than simply the partial sums going to $\infty$ - you're requiring that *all* the terms from a certain point are $1$.

Comment: Well, up to a typo, I guess, anyway.